# What would be the specific name of this type of bowl?

Tags: food

[image: bowl]
[image: bowl again]

The closest thing that I can find is Donburi? but that seems more like types of food not bowls.

ADDING:

This is about 15 and a half cm/6in
[image: 15 and a half]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a *chawan* (茶碗【ちゃわん】) rather than a *donburi*, because it's small. A typical *chawan* in my home is about 12 cm in diameter, and a *donburi* is about 18 cm or larger. *Chawan* literally means "tea bowl", but it's usually used for serving cooked rice ([See this](http://darumamuseum.blogspot.jp/2008/09/chawan-rice-bowl.html)).

A typical and cheap *chawan* doesn't have a lid, but some do. If you want to be specific, you can also say [蓋【ふた】付【つ】き茶碗 (*futa-tsuki chawan*, "chawan with a lid")](http://item.rakuten.co.jp/shoindo/c/0000000121/).

Alternatively you can use a more generic term, お椀 (*owan*, "bowl").

**EDIT**: A bowl of 15 cm can be called a 丼, and the name would partly depend on how this is intended to be used.

Comment: The ones I have are 15cm... which I bought as domburi... (by the way the op's hands might be bigger than ours... )

Comment: I update my post to show size. @choco mine is 15 cm :) 

So, if it's a Chawan, would it still be okay to still make other foods in it? or should I still stick to rice only?

Comment: @choco 実際に手に持って確かめたんですが、やっぱり僕の手より写真の手が大きかったみたいですw

Comment: @Hush564 If it's a Chawan people will normally use it as a rice bowl, if it's a Domburi they will normally use it for Domburi dishes, but I think it's all up to you what you use it for. An old lady I know uses her Chawan as Miso-soup bowls, and no one complains; it's just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @naruto いっぱい食べはる人やったらご飯茶碗として使ってもよさそうですね :D

Comment: @choco mkay, it's about the same size as all my other bowls so I could really use it for anything lol but I didn't know if there was a tradition or something surrounding it. Like how you don't put your chopsticks upright in rice or something like that.. I didn't know if there was anything disrespectful, I guess, is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 5):

I think your guess of *donburi* is correct.  The first sense line under 丼{どんぶり} in Shogakukan's 国語大辞典:

> 1. 厚手で深い陶製の食物を盛る鉢。どんぶりばち。
>      "A thick and deep ceramic bowl which food is served in. [...]"

The food sense is the last sense given for this term:

> 4. 「どんぶりもの（丼物）」の略。
>      "An abbreviation of *donburimono*".

**UPDATE:**

I think naruto is probably right: this may be a 茶碗{ちゃわん} instead.  I hadn't considered the scale, and I don't think I've ever seen an earthenware *chawan* with an earthenware lid before.  But given the size, this would be small for a 丼{どんぶり}.

**UPDATE 2:**

At 15cm, this could be a smaller 丼{どんぶり}. And regarding the term 丼{どんぶり} itself, this can refer to both the bowl and the foods traditionally served in this kind of bowl. The food is more specifically referred to as 丼{どんぶり}物{もの}.

Comment: Perhaps also worth mentioning the collocation 蓋付き丼.

Comment: I update my post to show size. Also, the word for donburi can be used as both describing the bowl and the meals in it? This is the link where I saw all the different foods.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donburi