# What is the difference between 「どんぶり」and「ちゃわん」

Tags: meaning, words, word-usage

I understand both are some kind of bowl but I would appreciate if someone could explain about the uses for each one.

Can a "ちゃわん" be used for cooked rice?
Can a "どんぶり" be used for ramen?

Comment: Nothing to do with language at all

Answer (score 2):

While there is a [history of the naming](http://gogen-allguide.com/to/donburi.html) of どんぶり, suffice to say that they are generally larger and normally used for meals rather than beverages.

There is no definitive consensus as to minimum size requirements to call something どんぶり or 丼鉢｛どんぶりばち｝(which is why one shop might call a middle-sized bowl a どんぶり while another calls it ちゃわん), but if it looks like it is more suited to a large *bowl of rice* (or noodle dish) than a *cup of tea* then most people would use どんぶり.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32659/

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that there was another word as どんぶりばち.